# What is meant by "restatement of the unique path lifting theorem" in terms of groupoids in May's Concise Course in Algebraic Topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

In chapter 3 of May's Concise Course in Algebraic Topology, the unique path lifting theorem is given as follows:

> **Theorem**. Let $p: E\to B$ be a covering, $b\in B$, and $e, e' \in F_b$ (where $F_b$ is the fiber of $b$).
>
> (i) A path $f: I\to B$ with $f(0) = b$ lifts uniquely to a path $g:I\to E$ such that $g(0) = e$ and $p\circ g = f$.
>
> (ii) Equivalent paths $f \simeq f': I\to B$ that start at $b$ lift to equivalent paths $g \simeq g': I\to E$ that start at $e$, hence $g(1) = g'(1)$.

Later on, the following statement is made:

> *Parts $(i)$ and $(ii)$ of the unique path lifting theorem can be restated as follows.*
> ***Proposition**. If $p: E\to B$ is a covering of spaces, then the induced functor $\Pi (p): \Pi (E)\to \Pi (B)$ is a covering of groupoids.*

Now, the unique path lifting theorem definitely implies this proposition, and I had no problem in showing that this is the case, but the phrase "can be restated as" led me to believe that these two statements can be considered equivalent, suggesting that this proposition implies that the unique path lifting theorem holds.

I got stuck trying to prove this, however; is this what they meant by "restatement"? If so, how can we show through this proposition that based paths are lifted uniquely? How can we further show that the related path-homotopies for the equivalence classes are lifted uniquely? Do we need to consider a 2-category structure on the fundamental groupoids?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to guess without seeing exactly how the author has formatted "Parts (i) and (ii) of the unique path lifting theorem".

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Editing my post to show the relevant parts of the theorem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the notation of Chapter 1, Section 2, the composite $p=\mathrm{id}_I\cdot c_0\colon I\to I$ of the identity path with the constant path at $0$ does not have the unique path-lifting property but does have $p_*\colon\Pi(I)\to\Pi(I)$ a covering of groupoids.

So equivalence of having unique path-lifting with being a covering map of groupoids is not what is meant. What is meant is that being a covering of groupoids is the algebraic/formal/non-topological aspect of unique path-lifting (as indicated by the opening "This point of view separates the essentials of the topology from the formalities..." of the section).